# What's the present day status of "kempt", has it survived in usage?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a possible positive form of ***unkempt***.

- My first choice was ***kempt***.

But I am not convinced of its usage. I want to be double sure that ***kempt*** has survived in day-to-day usage.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, unless you were trying to be humorous. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kempt%2Cunkempt%2Ctidy_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckempt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunkempt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctidy_ADJ%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I certainly use "kempt" in a humorous sense.  But then I also say "three boding" or "five boding", if "foreboding" doesn't quite fit.

Comment: [Relevant.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IngvNUaWvck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, Americans only use *kempt* when they’re trying to be cute. (Cf. Jim’s prior reply.) I’d opt for a more common antonym like *neat* or *tidy*.

Comment: As an American myself and speaking purely from my own experience I have never even heard of the single word "kempt" until reading this post! Though I do recognize and have used the word "unkempt" albeit not often.

Answer (score 3):

> *A rare word* after c. 1500; any **modern** **use** probably is a **[whimsical
>   back-formation from unkempt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=kempt)**.
>   (etymology.com)

From the fusing of un- “not” with kempt “neat” comes the adjective unkempt.
**Kempt has fallen out of use**, but unkempt persists as a popular word to describe anything unpolished, rough, or disorderly.
(vocabulary.com)

> Some [alternatives](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kempt):
>
> - neat, tidy, orderly, groomed, etc.